# Bayesian Linear regression (Ill-posed problem)

Tags: fitting, inverse, probability-or-statistics

I want to use the `ResourceFunction["BayesianLinearRegression"]` from Wolfram function repository.

With this function I want to solve the ill-posed problem
$y= A x$, where

$y$ is a known vector (1-d) of data,

$A$ is a 2-d matrix with parameters $\theta$.

The functional form of $A$ is known, so
you can calculate $A$ as function of the parameters.
The vector (1-d) $x$ are the unknown values that together with the parameters $\theta$ are the ones I want to calculate with the bayesian linear regression.

Thus, the question is how can you write that linear model in  `BayesianLinearRegression`.

Extra question: because this is an ill-posed problem, do you have to add an extra term such as the one in Tihkonov regularisation?

Many thanks in advance for your insights

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question here is. Could you please provide some code to clarify the problem? As for your question about Tihkonov regularisation: you don't do that in Bayesian regression. The priors already act as regularisation on the problem; there is no need to add it in artificially. In fact, Tihkonov regularisation is effectively equivalent to imposing a normal distribution prior on the model parameters.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I would not use the term (i.e., `tag`) „fitting“ for a Bayesian approach and instead talk about „estimation“.